# Copy, paste and save as a .xls file

Tags: file, save, copy, xls, paste

I need to define cell ranges to copy and paste in new worksbook under the name of column B (i.e. Alda.xls). How can I do it in VBA?

Thanks in advance.

```
  A      B              C         D     E    F   G    H      I
1999    ALDA    1/14/1999 12:00 1999    1   14  12  -20.2   36.1
1999    ALDA    1/14/1999 15:00 1999    1   14  15  -20.3   36.25
1999    ALDA    1/14/1999 18:00 1999    1   14  18  -20.4   36.4
1999    ALDA    1/14/1999 21:00 1999    1   14  21  -20.35  36.3
1999    ALDA    1/15/1999 0:00  1999    1   15  0   -20.3   36.2
1999    ALDA    1/15/1999 3:00  1999    1   15  3   -20.25  36.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I can do it manually but I have 200 of them in one worksheet. I just wanna know whether i can do it in VBA to make it fast.

If I have a code to define cell ranges and file name I think I can do it faster.